# Проблема с 3D моделью в Unity3D

Tags: unity3d, blender

Вопрос не совсем по программированию, но всё же задам

**Проблема такая:** когда я делаю модель и просматриваю её в других программах (например, в Paint 3D) все нормально, но когда я загружаю в Unity, капот почему-то пропадает

*Вот в блендере:*
[image: Фото в блендере]

*Вот в юнити*
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В превом-верхнем углу окна редактирования блендера нажми `Overlays`(в режиме редактирования) и поставь галочку `Face Orientation`, что бы увидеть, что у тебя полигоны капота вывернуты.

Comment: Да и вообще есть [blender.stack](https://blender.stackexchange.com/)!

Comment: @Yaroslav спасибо, буду знать